Service Console subtab loads data into other open subtab
I am having situation where opening (or loading) a custom subtab would load the data into already opened subtab.
Issue scenario:
We have a custom console app where upon creating a Case Record would fire/create two child subtabs (Workspace API, using AURA) with data pulling from API. So, if we create a second case record, it would load subtabs specific to the newly created case, but they also refreshing the data on the initially opened case record's subtab.
I tried to have a Case Id comparison (current Case Id == Case Id from the URL) to stop the data refresh in the old tab, but still the data flow across.
My understanding:
When we open a subtab within a Case record, the underlying LWCs are contextual and any new Case records would have instances of the same LWCs that wouldn't interfere with already open LWCs.
Anyone ever faced similar situation before, and if yes, how to resolve it?
